# JsTree contextmenu callback functions not firing

Tags: jstree

I am using the jstree library. A very nice library but I am stuck with one problem.  The callbacks of the contextmenu do not work.

I made a small working example - it should give an alert when you add / remove / rename nodes, but nothing happens..

Does anyone know why not and what is the solution?

You can see the working- not working example online:
http://www.leermetstrips.nl/Content/tree.htm

Or here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>JS tree example</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>      
    <script src="http://cachedcommons.org/cache/jquery-jstree/1.0.0/javascripts/jquery-jstree.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready( function() {
    var data = [{"data":"Root node","children":[{"data":"node one","children":[],"metadata":[{"action":"action12"}]}],"metadata":[{"action":"action11"}]}];
    $('#tree').jstree(
        {
            json_data: { data: data },
            plugins: ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "contextmenu", "crrm"],
            // TODO: this does not work, why?
            callback: {
                oncreate: function (NODE, REF_NODE, TYPE, TREE_OBJ, RB) {
                    alert('oncreate');
                },
                onrename: function (NODE, LANG, TREE_OBJ, RB) {
                    alert('onrename');
                },
                ondelete: function (NODE, TREE_OBJ, RB) {
                    alert('ondelete');
                }
            }
        }
        );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <h3>JS tree example</h3>
        <p>When adding, or deleting new nodes, there should be an alert. But there is none. Why?</p>
        <div id="tree" style="border:1px solid;"></div> 
        <p>Click on the tree with your right mouse button to add, rename or delete NEW tree nodes.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `callback` property in jstree core functionallity.
So remove this:

```
    callback: {
        oncreate: function (NODE, REF_NODE, TYPE, TREE_OBJ, RB) {
            alert('oncreate');
        },
        onrename: function (NODE, LANG, TREE_OBJ, RB) {
            alert('onrename');
        },
        ondelete: function (NODE, TREE_OBJ, RB) {
            alert('ondelete');
        }
    }
```

You need to bind jstree events outside the jstree object this way:

```
$('#tree').bind('create.jstree',function (node, ref) {
  alert('oncreate');
});

$('#tree').bind('rename.jstree',function (node, ref) {
  alert('onrename');
});

$('#tree').bind('remove.jstree',function (node, ref) {
  alert('ondelete');
});
```